# PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s error converting character to number

Tags: plsql

I have a problem with a pl/sql anonymous block. Although I can show the variables that get with select query, I get a casting error if I use it in update sentence.

My code looks like this:

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE

var1 scheme.table.column1%type; /* number[8,0] */
var2 scheme.table.column2%type; /* number[8,2] */

BEGIN

/* return simple value */
select t.column1, t.column2
into var1, var2
from scheme.table t
where <condition>

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Var1 is: ' || var1 || ' Var2 is:' || var2); /* fine!!*/

update scheme.table
set scheme.table.column1 = var1 + 1
where scheme.table.column2 = var2; /* that is line error*/

END;

/*
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error : error de conversión de carácter a número numérico o de valor
ORA-06512: en línea 58
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*/
```

Can somenone help me?

Comment: what is the value of var1 and var2 that gives you an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is correct, problem with compiler, sqldeveloper.

Comment: WHAT was the problem please specify ?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that var1+1 results in a number larger than number[8,0] for a record where column2=val2?

You query using "condition" but update using "column2=var2". So potentially you update many more rows than you may think you do.

Comment: Thank you Rene. I finally solved it. Code is correct, but no sqldeveloper. I compile same code sucessfully, so i was looking in wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-06502:  PL/SQL: numeric or value error string
Cause:  An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable declared NUMBER(2).
Action: Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so that values do not violate constraints.

**i think you error is the second choice.**

[reference to you error ORA-06502](http://ora-06502.ora-code.com/)

Comment: @user1398399 please provide the create table script especially its constraints

Comment: Thank you shareef. I finally solved it. Code is correct, but no sqldeveloper. I compile same code sucessfully, so i was looking in wrong place.